# Why am I getting an uncaught type error with the following code?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The purpose of this code is to have 3 divs that change color when clicked and when the two colors in divs on the left make up the one on the right the user receives a positive message either on the console or the DOM. I thought I had this entirely figured out but now whenever I click a div I get an uncaught type error in Chrome that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8v1vhLL6/)

```
var squares1 = document.getElementsByClassName('square1');
var squares2 = document.getElementsByClassName('square2');
var squares3 = document.getElementsByClassName('square3');

//change squares1 to either red,green, or blue
for(var i = 0; i < squares1.length; i++) {
    squares1[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}
//change squares2 to either red, green, or blue
for(var i = 0; i < squares2.length; i++) {
    squares2[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}
//changes squares3 to either red, green, blue, magenta, cyan, etc
for(var i = 0; i < squares3.length; i++) {
    squares3[i].addEventListener("click", changeColors);
}

function changeColor(event){
    if(event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)';
        checkColors();
    }
    else if (event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 255, 0)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';
        checkColors();

    }
    else
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
        checkColors();

    }
}

function changeColors(event){
    if(event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 255)';
        checkColors();
    }
    else if (event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 255)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
        checkColors();

    }
    else if (event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 255, 0)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';
        checkColors();

    }
    else if (event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 255, 255)';
        checkColors();

    }
    else if (event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 255, 255)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 255)';
        checkColors();

    }
    else if (event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 255)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)';
        checkColors();

    }
    else if (event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 255, 0)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
        checkColors();

    }
    else if (event.target.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 255, 0)')
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 255, 255)';
        checkColors();

    }

    else
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
        checkColors();

    }
}

function checkColors(){
    if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 0, 0)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 0, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 255, 0)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(0, 0, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(0, 255, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 0, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(0, 255, 0)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 255, 0)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(0, 255, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
else{youMissed;}

}

function gotIt(){
    console.log("You got it!")
}

function youMissed(){
    console.log("Try Again!")
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8v1vhLL6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `getElementsByClassName` to fetch an array of elements that match your class name.

When binding your events, you correctly use the `[0]` index of that array to grab the first item in it:

```
squares1[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
```

However, in the `checkColors()` function you try to grab the `backgroundColor` of the entire array:

```
squares1.style.backgroundColor
```

An array doesn't have a background color, use `squares1[0]` like you did in the event listener to get the properties of the first element.

Comment: Also note that your code is very inefficient, there is a lot of repeated code you should wrap in more generic functions.

Comment: I understand that  it is pretty inefficient as I get better with working in Javascript I will try to use less redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

because this code:

```
function checkColors(){
    if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 0, 0)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 0, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 255, 0)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(0, 0, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(0, 255, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 0, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(0, 255, 0)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 255, 0)';
        gotIt;
    }
    else if (squares1.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 255, 0)' && squares2.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
        squares3.style.backgroundColor='rgb(0, 255, 255)';
        gotIt;
    }
else{youMissed;}

}
```

checks the `squares1` etc.. as if it is a single element while actually it is a nodeList (so you need to check each `squares1[i]` and so on). probably same issue may be elsewhere in the code, did not check all.

Answer (score 1):

Get elements by class name returns an array of elements.  You need to specify which one.  Try squares1[0] etc.

Comment: Just seen that Stephan beat me to it!